# How to manually select combo box in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, winforms

i would like to ask a question.
i have a five button and one combo box in my windows form.
combo box have 5 items to select in their collection.

eg.

> 1.John
>
> 2.Steve
>
> 3.Seven
>
> 4.Jhone
>
> 5.Eistein

like that.

i want to manually select the items in combo box with button's event.
when i click Seven button,that combo box will automatically select John to Seven.
Or select Eistein that combo box's select item will automatically select Seven to Eistein.
How can i do that?

Please let me know if you can do that.
Thanks your for your time. :)

Comment: when you say "Seven to Eistein" are you meaning you want to select multiple items in the combo box? Standard Combo box does NOT support multi item selection, for that you would neeed to use a ListBox control.

Comment: No.sorry for your miss understanding.
i means like that when i click seven button,that combo box's selected items must change to Eistein.like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FindStringExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb.aspx):

```
private void einsteinButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int item = ComboBox.FindStringExact("Einstein");
    if (item >= 0)
        ComboBox.SelectedItem = item;
}
```

Comment: It's not change in my combo box.Why?

Comment: when i debug,my combo box's count is five and not change eistein.it's still old selected seven item.Please...

Comment: Please update the question with code, because it's impossible for me to get what you mean.